# Slick does not know how to map the given types - Option(DateTime.now)

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I am trying to do this (on Play Framework):

```
db.run(users.filter(_.id === id).map(_.deleted).update(Option(DateTime.now)))
```

But it's throwing a compilation error:

> No matching Shape found. Slick does not know how to map the given
>   types. Possible causes: T in Table[T] does not match your *
>   projection,  you use an unsupported type in a Query (e.g. scala List),
>   or you forgot to import a driver api into scope.   Required level:
>   slick.lifted.FlatShapeLevel
>        Source type: slick.lifted.Rep[Option[org.joda.time.DateTime]]    Unpacked type: T
>        Packed type: G

Version of Slick 3.0.3.
How can i fix this bug?

```
class UserTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "user") {

  def id = column[Int]("id")

  def name = column[String]("name")

  def age = column[Int]("age")

  def deleted = column[Option[DateTime]]("deleted")

  override def * =
    (id, name, age, deleted) <> ((User.apply _).tupled, User.unapply)
}

case class User(
  id: Int = 0,
  name: String,
  age: Int,
  deleted: Option[DateTime] = None
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define your table, there is a column type mapper in scope for `DateTime`. Something like

```scala
implicit val dtMapper = MappedColumnType.base[org.joda.time.DateTime, Long](
  dt => dt.getMillis,
  l => new DateTime(l, DateTimeZone.UTC)
)
```

for example. This mapper must also be in scope at the location where you construct your query, otherwise Slick will not know how to convert what you've written into a SQL query.

You can either import the mapper, if you would like to keep the query separate from the table, or define the query in the same file where you define `UserTable`. A common pattern is to wrap the table in a trait, say `UserRepository`, and define both the table and the queries within that trait.

[See this page](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html) for more information on how implicit scope works.

Comment: I added this code in UserTable, but the error remained

Comment: `class UserTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "user") {

  implicit val dtMapper  = MappedColumnType.base[DateTime, Long](d => d.getMillis, d => new DateTime(d))

  def id: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("id")

  def name: Rep[String] = column[String]("name")

  def age: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("age")

  def deleted: Rep[Option[DateTime]] = column[Option[DateTime]]("deleted")

  override def * =
  (id, name, age, deleted) <> ((User.apply _).tupled, User.unapply)
}`

Comment: The mapper must be available, i.e., in "implicit scope", at the location where the `update` query is defined, *as well as* where the table is defined. To understand implicit scope better, see https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html.

Comment: Thank you, everything worked. I just added `implicit val dtMapper: JdbcType[DateTime] with BaseTypedType[DateTime] = MappedColumnType.base[DateTime, Long](d => d.getMillis, d => new DateTime(d)) ` to the function that makes the update (in DAO).

Comment: I'm glad that worked! But please ensure that the same mapper is being used for the table and the query; if the mappers differ (for instance one maps to epoch millis and the other to seconds) there will be bugs.